# Unable to call a Google WebApps server side function from HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a simple Google WebApps script. It is loading a modal dialog, and then calling a server side function when the dialog is submitted.

This is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
          function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
              google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
              google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>My Team</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="myTeam"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
       
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the script:

```
function doGet() {
  var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var ui = document.getBody().appendListItem("hello!")

    DocumentApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('The Bomb')
      .addItem('Simple Kafka Topic', 'sboKafka')
      .addSeparator()
      .addToUi();
}

function sboKafka() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SBOKafka')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  
  DocumentApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Simple Kafka Topic');
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  Logger.log("processForm");
  var zt = formObject.myTeam;
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().appendListItem(zt)
}
```

However, when the dialog is submitted, the server side function is not run.

I am seeing the following error in the browser error console.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://docs.google.com' from frame with URL 'https://n-e2b764askqfnjofaraeymmf47os6fnoc372huli-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. 

The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE 1: This is how I am testing this out....

1. Close the script editor window and the google doc.
2. Go to Drive -> Open the Doc
3. Click on Tools -> Script Editor. This opens the script editor window
4. Go to script editor window
5. Click on Run -> Run Function -> doGet
6. Go back to word doc. Click on The Bomb -> Simple Kafka Topic
7. Dialog pops up.
8. Enter a string in team name.
9. Submit
10. Nothing happens

Expected: Text in document to change.

Answer (score 2):

I thought that in this case, the reason of your issue might be due to the submit of the form. So as a simple modification for resolving your issue, how about the following modifications?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `return false` is used.

#### From:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
```

#### To:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this); return false;">
```

- In this modification, `false` is returned.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `Event.preventDefault()` is used.

#### From:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
```

#### To:

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); handleFormSubmit(this);">
```

### References:

- Related thread.

  - [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3350247)
- [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: I think that it's also necessary to add `preventDefault()` to the form submit event listener as is done in the Google Apps Script about Server-Client communication.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for replying. Yes. At first, I thought 2 patterns of `handleFormSubmit(this); return false;` and `event.preventDefault(); handleFormSubmit(this);`. When `handleFormSubmit(this); return false;` is used, `false` is returned with the asynchronous process. So in this case, I thought that this modification can resolve the OP's issue. But from your replying, I think that when both patterns are suggested, they will be more useful. So I added it. Thank you for your always support.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. But no, this suggested workaround doesnt work.

Comment: @feroze Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. And I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, from `But no, this suggested workaround doesnt work.`, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested your script using my suggested modification, I can confirm that your error message could be removed. But I would like to support you. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: I did not try the `PreventDefault` suppression of the event. I thought that was in the sample just because they want to show the URL of the uploaded file without dismissing the dialog... But I can try.

Comment: @feroze Thank you for replying. Although I tested your script using both patterns in my answer again, I could confirm that the message you want to remove was removed. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this. In order to replicate your current situation,  I would like to confirm it. Your current script is the same with your script in your question, and you reflected my suggested modifications for the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: hi! Yeah, so I used exactly the same code pasted here. It doesnt work. I added the `event.preventDefault()` as well, in the form.

Comment: I will update my question to say how I invoke this. Maybe something wrong with that...

Comment: @feroze Thank you for the additional information. I tested your added flow. But unfortunately, when my suggested modifications are used, the message you want to remove is not shown. So I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this. I have a question. In your situation, what browser are you using? In my environment, I tested it using Chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome as well.

Comment: @feroze Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when Chrome is used for testing your script and your flow in your updated question and my suggested modification patterns, no error occurs. I cannot replicate your situation of `It doesnt work`. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.